# Call method of outer class instance from inside module

Tags: ruby, scope, rubygems

I'm looking to create a Gem that can be called as follows

```
# initialization
location = DarkSky::Location.new [45, -90]

# calling certain methods
location.current.temperature
location.tomorrow.temperature_high # not shown below
```

Currently, my code is structured like this (many methods shelled for this post)

`location.rb`

```
module DarkSky
  # other methods are here, as this is for a Gem
  class Location
    def initialize(location)
      @location = location
    end

    def full_data
      # return common data between `Current` and `Tomorrow` classes
      {
        currently: {
          temperature: 42
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

`current.rb`

```
module DarkSky
  class Location
    module Current
      def self.temperature
        full_data[:currently][:temperature] # this line
      end
    end

    # alias name for client simplicity
    def current
      Current
    end
  end
end
```

In the second block, I'm looking to call `full_data` from the first block. The problem I'm having is that `full_data` is an instance method, while I can only access it from inside the `Location` scope (not the inner `Current` scope)

I've searched quite a bit, but haven't been able to find anything similar to this, where the method is an *instance* method, not a *class* method.

Side note - it doesn't matter if `Current` is a class or module. I'm good with a solution either way.

Comment: The class method `temperature` would have to create an instance of `Location` to call `full_data`. I doubt that's your intent. Why do you want `full_data` to be an instance method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Each location has its own data. The reason I'm using `Current` and such is solely for namespace purposes. My thought is that it would have to create an instance, which doesn't let me achieve the desired behavior at the beginning of the post. The `Location` data is cached to avoid many requests, which is why instantiating multiple classes isn't the right way to go about the problem.

Comment: "Call method of **outer class** instance from inside module" – There is no such thing as an "outer class" in Ruby. Ruby doesn't have nested classes like Beta or Newspeak has.

Comment: Why is this a module at all. Since full_data is a requirement the binding would be extremely tight. Why not just make these instance methods of `Location`?

Comment: @engineersmnky The intent is to match the API in the first code block. I could absolutely do `current_temperature` as a method, but that's not the way I'd prefer to call it ("current" should be a namespace, as it's data is separate).

Comment: Namespaced maybe but modularilized probably not why not just make it a class?

Comment: @engineersmnky Actually figured it out myself. Key detail is that there's only be one instance of `Current` or similar. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that in this situation, there will only ever be one instance of `Current` or similar, this can be accomplished by creating a class instance upon `Location` initialization, and using `attr_reader` to access it.

Here's working code, based on the original post.

`location.rb`

```
module DarkSky
  # other methods are here, as this is for a Gem
  class Location
    attr_reader :current

    def initialize(location)
      @location = location
      @current = Current.new self # here's the "hidden" initialization with the instance as a parameter
    end

    def full_data
      # return common data between `Current` and `Tomorrow` classes
      {
        currently: {
          temperature: 42
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

`current.rb`

```
module DarkSky
  class Location
    class Current
      def initialize(location)
        # keep a reference to the location (for the shared data)
        @location = location
      end

      def apparent_temperature
        @location.full_data[:currently][:temperature]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This allows for what appears to be a namespace, but in reality is just a getter for the class instance, which then lets you get the individual methods.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **every** method call has an additional parameter besides those in the parameter list, which is the receiver of the method. If no receiver is explicitly written, `self` is assumed as the receiver.

With respect to data sharing, there is no relationship between the module DarkSky::Location::Current and the class DarkSky::Location. Your method call of `full_data` does not specify an explicit receiver, so it assumes `self` as a receiver. In your case, `self` equals `DarkSyk::Location::Current`, and there is no method `full_data` in this module.

Let's assume that your method `full_data` **really** needs to access its DarkSky::Location object; in the code you posted, this is not the case, but I guess that you have stripped down your code to make it easier to understand your problem. In this case, you also have to provide such a Location object; how else should `full_data` know how to calculate the result?

Of course, if `full_data` really does **not** need any instance variables from `Location`, it should be a class method of Location, not an instance method.

In your case, I guess a Location object stores the (weather-)data for a certain location, and your `temperature` method returns the temperature. But for which location should it return the temperaturs? Tokyo or Vienna? Without knowing the place, it does not make sense to know the temperature. One way to make it work is to add the place as a parameter:

```
module Current
  # where  : Object of class DarkSky::Location
  def self.temperature(where)
    where.full_data[:currently][:temperature] # this line
  end
end
```

This is only an example. Whether it fits your application or not, I don't know.

Comment: Readers are grown-ups who don't need words bold-faced to understand what they are reading. Also, "really", as used here, is a nothing-word.

Comment: Maybe I don't have this level of intelligence yet, but at least to me, it helps if words are *emphasized* in some way, if one should pay particular attention to them. Thanks also for pointing out, that "really" is not appropriate here; not being a native speaker, I made the mistake to translate it a bit too literally from my language. If I understand you correctly, I can leave out the word without change in meaning of the whole sentence.

Comment: In everyday conversation one might say “X really needs Y” to suggest that X will have a big problem (not just a problem :-)) if it doesn’t get Y.  Here, where a precise answer to a coding problem is required, X either “needs” Y or it doesn’t. As for setting words in bold face, not only is it unnecessary, but it suggests the reader might not understand what you have written without the emphasis, which some readers may not appreciate. Highlighting words in notes, for example, is fine, but only if they are your notes.